# Multiple integral over a k-dimensional simplex

Tags: calculus, integration

How to prove
$$\int_{0}^{t}\int_{t_1}^t\cdots\int_{t_{n-1}}^tf(t_1)f(t_2)\cdots f(t_n)\,dt_n\cdots\,dt_2dt_1=\frac{\left(\int_{0}^{t}f(x)\,dx\right)^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Ummm... is the upper limit of the first integral $t_0$?

Comment: @David Putting `\limits` is not a reason to edit.

Comment: Yes it is... it squeezes the broad integral so that the equation fits on a single line.  It is also much easier to read.  The current version (yours) is a mess... as everyone can plainly see.  You can't even see the full equation!!!

Comment: Of *course* it is on a line... and extends *OUTSIDE THE WINDOW*!

Comment: It isn't.  I'm viewing it on a 1024x768 Firefox window and zoomed to 170%.

Comment: Anyway, there is something wrong with the integrals because there are $n+1$ of them (and $f$s) on the left but only $n$ on the right.  Can OP check what is really intended?

Comment: Note that the domain of integration can be written as $0 < t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n$.  Consider the integrals over the other domains of similar form in which the variables are permuted.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks! I made a mistake about it, so I changed the subscript from $t_0,t_1,\cdots t_n$ to $t_1,t_2,\cdots t_n$.

Comment: Is this homework (where an instructor is expecting rigor) or are you interested in an explanation? (zoidberg basically wrote the explanation)

Comment: @runway44 It's not the homework, just from a paper's supplement material. I feel I can understand this equation, but I don't know how to prove it exactly.

Comment: What if you called the domain of integrate $I$, considered other domains of integration $I_{\pi}$ for nonidentity permutations $\pi$, said the integral is the same over the different domains is all the same because the product $f(t_1)\cdots f(t_n)$ is symmetric, and the sum of these integrals over the different domains is the same as the integral over $[0,1]^n$, which is the 1D integral to the $n$th power. Since there are $n!$ domains $I_{\pi}$, we're done. Would you consider that a proof?

Comment: @runway44 Get it, thank you!